# Array modifier's merge is deforming the object

Tags: modifiers

Instead of smoothing out the surface, the merge option deforms the entire shape. Any idea why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, try increasing the subdivision levels to 6. I reccomend playing with the modifiers, it helps.

Comment: Increasing subdivision levels didn't help.

Comment: How did you make that shape?  Are there zillions of edges in the bevel? Personally, I would Array and Curve as a sharp, un-bevelled star, and bevel the solid afterwards. Maybe the 'Merge' in the Array is catching too many vertices.

Comment: @Robin Betts  Actually it's a simple star made out of a circle shape. Subdivision modifier made the edges appear to have been beveled. I deleted the subdiv modifier but it didn't help. Check the new screenshot that I've added from the star in edit mode.

Comment: @Mh.A Can you attach your .blend file? And don't remove the subdiv modifier, it will make the result even blockier.

Comment: @Chaudhry Yousuf added .blend file to original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to drag the subdivision surface modifier on the top of the modifier stack, over the array modifier. Its your choice if you want to use the array modifier's merge option. [image]

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: You're Welcome (: